# Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: (at Binary XML file line #125): <meta-data> requires an android:value or android:resource attribute

Tags: android, xml-parsing, google-play-services, metadata, android-manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.loginpage">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LoginPage" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:exported="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Entry"
            android:exported="true" >
        </activity>
      
        <activity
             android:name=".HousePref"
             android:exported="true" />
        <activity
             android:name=".Profile"
             android:exported="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

changed position of intent filter to change my first page.
Got debug Manifest xml errors. I put the intent filter back to original place. since then getting these errors.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You `meta-data` tag seems correct.
Check you are using the latest [Google Play services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) version in your `build.gradle`.
Try also `Build > Clean Project` and `Build > Rebuild Project`.

Comment: I checked, I am using the latest google play services. I am still getting the same error after clean and rebuild project.